# Greedy Sort Of Array By Value - #numOfSameTypeSoFar

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I wish to sort in a specific way according to `value` & `type`. In simple words, I wish to sort by `value` but to also give bonus points to less popular `types` according to which other elements have already been chosen as `bigger`. The array looks something like this:

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 7
            [type] => A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => A
            [value] => 5
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => B
            [value] => 4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => A
            [value] => 34
        )
```

And I would like to sort it by `value`, but also mix things up and give some weight to the `type` parameter. The more I already have top places with `type` = X, the more I will give bonus value to other `types`. I've tried this:

```
usort($myArray, function(&$a, &$b) {
        static $typeCounts;

        // to mix things up a bit
        $bValue = $b['value'] - 10*$typeCounts[$b['type']];
        $aValue = $a['value'] - 10*$typeCounts[$a['type']];
        $toReturn = $bValue - $aValue; // DESC

        // update type selected
        if ($toReturn > 0) {
            $typeCounts[$b['type']]++;
        } else {
            $typeCounts[$a['type']]++;
        }

        return $toReturn;
    });
```

The given example array should result looking `[4], [1], [3], [2]` Where `[3]` was chosen over `[2]` because there are already two elements of type A above him. I assume I can implement my own sort function, or sort the array several times, but was looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What "wight" does mean?

Comment: ^ This. Also, where did the "two" in "two elements" come from? Magic? Why not three, or five, or a thousand and one?

Comment: @Jon I'm trying to do a greedy sort algorithm, that when choosing element #3 in the sorted array, it will take into account the `types` of #1 and #2. Of-course "two" is just an example, and this will happen to all elements. this is why in the sort function i've calculated the effective value as the `value` field minus the number of elements in the same type he's seen so far  `$b['value'] - 10*$typeCounts[$b['type']]`. But the sort function ofcourse doesn't execute just when 'select element #X' which is the reason I'm looking for a diff approach.

Comment: @AlmaDo I'm trying to achieve that I will have a parameter that will effect how much the sort will avoid consecutive selection of the same type over and over again. Consider type to be a 'photo' or 'text', when a user browses, I want the page to also include photos, even if they are less important, even if my main sorting parameter tells differently.

Comment: @AlmaDo not sure what you're asking about "wight" ? Did I say that?